# How can I hide the cmd console from my Matlab Exe?

Tags: matlab, matlab-deployment, matlab-compiler

I've a problem with my EXE file, generated by Matlab Development tool. 
Pratically, even choosing "Windows StandAlone Mode", when I run the EXE, always appears the hated black CMD console.

How can I avoid this apparition?

Thanks for the help to everyone who Try...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a utility published on the Mathworks website that does just that. http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/3909-suppress-command-window

Another solution would be to use another application to launch your MATLAB exe silently.

In `C#` for example you could start your MATLAB exe with the following arguments to hide the console window:

```
var process = new Process();
process.StartInfo.FileName = "path to your exe"
process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;

// ...

process.Start();
```

Comment: In C# I am glad to never have to do that again. We completely switched over to [ILNumerics](http://ilnumerics.net) ;)

Comment: @user492238 ILNumerics is nice but it can't replace all the MATLAB toolboxes, unfortunately.